# jquery text update issue

Tags: jquery, html

My task is to create a dynamical price list with checkbox. 
When im checking an item price should be updated, but its not working for me. can anyone help me to find my mistake?

```js
$('#iPhone4').click(function(e) {
  $('#ip4').attr('src', 'pics/iphone/4.png');
  $('#modelForm').show('slow');
  $('#modelHeader').text('iPhone 4');
  var akku = 25;
  var pr = 0;
  if ($('#akku').is(':checked')) {
    $pr = $pr + $akku;
    $('#preise4').text('$pr');
  }

});
```

```html
<p class="problBer">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="akku">Akku<span class="cena">45€</span>
  </input>
</p>

<div id="pre">
  <p id="preise4">Euro</p>
</div>
```

Comment: $pr = $pr + $akku; try replacing with pr = parseFloat(pr) + parseFloat(akku); and $('#preise4').text('$pr'); by $('#preise4').text(pr);

Comment: thanks for your reply. I edited my code with your advices, but now im getting "pr" in #preise 4 p.

Comment: ok it works now. the right line is $('#preise4').text($pr)

Comment: Posting as answer to help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

`$pr = $pr + $akku;` try replacing by `pr = parseFloat(pr) + parseFloat(akku);`

And

`$('#preise4').text('$pr');` by `$('#preise4').text(pr);`

OR

`$('#preise4').text('$pr');` by `$('#preise4').text($pr);`

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, i am using two variable akku  and pr static for now...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var akku = 25;
  var pr = 0;

$('#akku').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#preise4').text("Euro "+akku );
  } else {
    $('#preise4').text("Euro "+pr);
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="problBer">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="akku">Akku<span class="cena">45€</span>
  </input>
</p>

<div id="pre">
  <p id="preise4">Euro</p>
</div>
```